# How do I put backticks in a column name called key for hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, key, reserved-words

I have a MySQL DB table which I cannot modify but have to insert values into. It has a column called `key` which I need to insert into.

Now, my .hbm.xml file has:

```
    <property name="key"
          type="string"
          column="key" />
```

The insert query generated hence fails. On adding [key], the generated SQL now contained `key` but this also failed. On checking in MYSql Workbench, I found that `key` can work.

However, if I change this in the file mentioned above, it reverts to the "key" as when using [key]. Can someone guide me as to how I can add `key` and bring about the required insert?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a hibernate configuration option for this. It needs Hibernate 3.5 which I'm not sure if you're using based on your use of hbm files.

In your hibernate config set

```
hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

List of environment config is [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Environment.html)

Comment: For mysql, I don't think that will work. In the end I got it solved by doing column="'key'"

Comment: @gran_profaci: it fixed the issue for me and I'm using MySQL 5.5.

Comment: @Lionel This add backticks to the table names and the db name but, not to the column names.