# Table named order - hibernate generates invalid SQL - table name to be qualified

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Using Hibernate and MySQL, I have this table 
named `Order` and a respective `Order` bean.

```
@Entity                                      
@org.hibernate.annotations.SelectBeforeUpdate(true)                   
@org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate(true)                        
@Table(name = "order")
public class Order {                         
   ... 
}
```

I get this error. I believe the reason is that `order` is
a reserved word in SQL, so the table name has to be qualified.

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order order4...`

What is the way to solve this in a RDBMS-independent way?
I mean I don't want to simply qualify my table name with

```
@Table(name = "`order`")
```

if possible (because the backtick symbol is a MySQL-dependent qualifier).

What is the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: It is always a good pratice not to use reserved words as tables, fields and what so ever on your model. I would go just for changing the table name, something like `orders`

Comment: @JorgeCampos I know this good practice. Thanks but that doesn't help me. I cannot change the table name. I am looking for a real solution here in terms of hibernate configuration.

Comment: So you may looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17204648/460557 or this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3463189/460557 or even this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3368289/460557

Comment: @JorgeCampos Great, thanks, this works. I used the standard escaping `@Table(name = "\"order\"")`. This is translated perfectly by Hibernate to the backtick escaping (in the generated SQL code). Problem solved.

Comment: That is great I will mark this question as a duplicate then.